# How do I get rid of underlines under links? Text-decoration: none; not working

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I can't stop the underlines being displayed in my menu (the gigantic blue block on the left).

http://jades-world.com/schoolassign/

Can someone please point out if I am missing something? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are applying text-decoration: none only on hover. Appy it to .nav a { text-decoration: none;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use,

```
.topmenu a, .topmenu a:visited, .submenu a, .submenu a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can always try [firebug](http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php), which is most helpful tool for front-end web developers.

Comment: I want underlines elsewhere though :).

Comment: Thank you!! I was having such a hard time with it.

Answer (score 2):

On your base.css file,

```
.topmenu a, .topmenu a:visited {
    color: #0A95C5;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
nav a {
text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

In the link that you mentioned there is only

```
nav a:hover, nav a:visited {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none!important;
}
```